# How to save a image file from a wordcloud generated with Texthero

Tags: python

Here is my code - However it saves an empty file - Thanks in advance for your help.

```
df['Text_cleaned'] = hero.clean(df['Text'])

with open('wordcloud.jpg', 'w') as f:
    print(hero.wordcloud(df.Text_cleaned, max_words=50), file=f)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am working in Flask app where I need to return an image as png in my response. My code will return an image to the incoming request, you can mold it according to your requirements. hero.wordcloud accepts an optional param return_figure, you need to set it true.

```
ax=hero.wordcloud(Kto['new'], max_words=200, height=400, width=600,return_figure=True)
plt.figure(figsize=(18, 12))
img = ax.get_figure()
output = io.BytesIO()
FigureCanvas(img).print_png(output)
return Response(output.getvalue(), mimetype='image/png')
```